# IntelliJ IDEA Android Application Gradle unable to resolve dependancies

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

I have created a blank android activity from the intelliJ templates. When I have gone to build it, I get the message:

```
build.gradle: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.+.
```

Please could you help me work out what is wrong, I have tried searching on google for answers but none of them are clear.

[image: intelliJ-IDEA error screenshot]]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm facing this issue only when using Intellij Idea IDE with Android plugin.

Current workaround involves below steps:

1. First In **Project>app>build.gradle** file replace line 
   `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'29.+'`
    with 
   `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'`
    and save it.
2. After that click **File > Re-Import Gradle Project**, this will remove those errors

Comment: Great , this solution is the best !